# Convert string to date using moment.js

Tags: string, angular, date, momentjs, string-to-datetime

This my model.ts

```
 export class Feature2 {

 requestRouteTemplate: string;
 requestMethod: string;
 numberCount: number;
 requestDate: date;

 constructor(values: Object = {}) {
  Object.assign(this, values);  
 }
}
```

This is component.ts

```
   this.datas2 = [
  {
    'requestRouteTemplate': 'api/Tasks',
    'requestMethod': 'POST',
    'numberCount': 6,
    'requestDate': '07/01/2017',
  },
  {
    'requestRouteTemplate': 'api/Tasks',
    'requestMethod': 'POST',
    'numberCount': 3,
    'requestDate': '07/02/2017',
  },
```

I want to convert the request date variable from string to date using the moment library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your constructor add: `this.requestDate = moment(values.requestDate, "MM-DD-YYYY").toDate();`

See the documentation:

- https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/
- https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/

Answer (score 2):

You have to create pipe like below

```
//datePipe.ts 

 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    import moment from 'moment';
    @Pipe({
        name: 'datex'
    })

    export class DatexPipe implements PipeTransform {
        transform(value: any, format: string = ""): string {
            // Try and parse the passed value.
            var momentDate = moment(value);

            // If moment didn't understand the value, return it unformatted.
            if (!momentDate.isValid()) return value;

            // Otherwise, return the date formatted as requested.
            return momentDate.format(format);
        }
    }
```

and then you can use it in html page

```
{{datas2.requestDate | datex:'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'}}
```