# Angular: Format Moment to show as Date in html

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have a data type of type Moment in Angular, everytime it displays in Angular, it exhibits as

```
<div>{{dateStart}}</div>

Fri Mar 08 2019 20:24:35 GMT-0800
```

How do I display to show, '3/8/2019' ?

If converting in Typescript, we have to take existing class, and recreate new class with last two data types as date. Just curious if there is Displayformat Angular in HTML or Pipe function? Where its converted in HTML?

```
export class Address {
    fullName: string;
    mailingAddress: string;
    phoneNumber: string;
    emailAddress: string;
    dateStart?: moment.Moment;
    dateEnd?: moment.Moment;
```

**Resource questions:**

[Angular: Format Moment to show as Date in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58776428/angular-format-moment-to-show-as-date-in-html/58776437#58776437)

[Convert string to date using moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45029300/convert-string-to-date-using-moment-js)

[How to set today date and time as default in angular-moment-picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44201003/how-to-set-today-date-and-time-as-default-in-angular-moment-picker)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the [`date pipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#datepipe) as,

```
{{dateStart | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
```

To remove leading zeros, do this

```
{{dateStart | date: 'M/d/yyyy'}}
```

Comment: simple as that, remove one M {{dateStart | date: 'M/dd/yyyy'}}

Comment: yep, just gave points, stack wouldn't let me accepted answer within 5 min of question, thanks, have a question on bounty here by the way, thanks again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58707528/angular-8-formcontrolname-inside-component-multiple-nested-levels-below